# How to enable communication within a .net maui app and java app that will run in background as service

Tags: java, android, printing, maui, point-of-sale

I am developing a .net maui application for bill payment and receipt generation. the target platform is a payment terminal that runs on Android 8.1. according to the documentation it is possible to print via a Java application. I did the test by coding a java application and it works fine. However I don't know how to integrate this functionality of the payment terminal to the .net maui application. what I'm looking for now is a way to enable communication between the .net maui app and the java app, so the java app will run as a service and the .net maui app can call a function from the app Java by giving it the informations to launch the printing of a receipt.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  This is a basic rule of the site.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, it is my first time.

Comment: you need to [edit] your question to fix the problem if you expect anyone to help you

Comment: Are you asking how to communicate between two apps, or how to fix a bug when adding a java library to Maui? These are not the same topic, yet you mention both. Please correct title and question contents to talk about only ONE of those possibilities. This will make the discussion clearer.

Comment: I edited the post to only deal with communication within java app and .net maui app.